# Getting the details about the boundary of the objects in images using Tensor flow?

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I am trying to build a model to detect different objects in images using the Tensor flow object detection API. [image]

[image]

I have images some thing like this, objects placed on a white board. I Can use tensor flow to detect objects in the images, but is it possible to get the boundaries so that I can crop at particular place if I think specific image is necessary and use my Image processing technique further.

Answer (score 2):

```
print 'classes:', output_dict['detection_classes']
print 'scores:', output_dict['detection_scores']
print 'labels:', output_dict['detection_boxes']
```

Usually the the detected box dimensions are normalized. You can expand them by

```
def expand_dimensions(Tbox, w, h):
    # w, h are the width and height of the image
    # Tbox= [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]
    #         0     1      2    3
    Xbox = [Tbox[0] * h, Tbox[1]*w,
            Tbox[2] * h, Tbox[3]*w]
    return Xbox
```

Once you know the end points you can crop the image.